# How to test JERSEY controller methods with UriInfo

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, jersey

I am writing unit test for a JERSEY project.

For methods with no query string , I can just instantiate controller and call the method.

Also work for argument in the path because they appear as string arguments of the method.

But when I get queryStrings the mode has a special argument `(@Context UriInfo url)`

How can I build the UriInfo argument in my unit tests ?
Why does this class has no constructor ?

Comment: Its highly unusual to test a Jersey resource outside of a container, and kind of counterproductive. Things that wont work? Container injected resources, path interpretation, parameter extraction, sub-resource locators ... the list goes on. If you really want to test your JAX-RS resource classes you should do so from the ***client*** side.

Comment: I can also run some test in a tomcat container but then in terms of debugging unit test of running code coverage analysis. I am totally blind because these run into 2 separate process.

Comment: If you run a standalone Tomcat with your app deployed, you can run a suit of jUnit tests against it that use a client library to test the resources. You can use the Jersey client libraries or even Apache HttpComponents to create these tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UriInfo` is an interface so you can't create its object directly. You need to subclass it and create your own `UriInfo` class. So your uriinfo class should convert String uri/url into UriInfo object.

```
public class UriInformation implements UriInfo {
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> pathParamMap;
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParamMap;
    public UriInformation(UriInfo uriInfo) {
        //parse uriInfo 
    }
 //setters/getters
}
```

So this way you can unit test your resources without running it inside tomcat/server.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using Mockito in your tests, you could mock out UriInfo instead:

```
import java.net.URI;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

UriInfo mockUriInfo = mock(UriInfo.class);
when(mockUriInfo.getRequestUri()).thenReturn(new URI("http://www.test.com/go"));
```

Comment: which URI class did you use here?